# Http Error :500.00 While Trying To Host WCF Service on IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

[screenshot of http error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78NN6.png)
. I am having a windows error when I try to host my WCF service on IIS. The interpreted error code from windows Err.exe told me that it is called error_cluster_membership_halt.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided in the error screenshot you uploaded? You can refer to this link http://www.windowshelp.world/ERROR_CLUSTER_MEMBERSHIP_HALT.html for help on error_cluster_membership_halt Error . There could be some tools to fix this error. Download and try running it on your machine

Comment: What do you see in system or application event log ?

Comment: Sujith the link didnt work, and I have tried everything possible.

Comment: Rohith, the app event log says ;An application has reported as being unhealthy. The worker process will now request a recycle. Reason given: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
. The data is the error.

Comment: Sujith Actually the error code 0x80131704 is CLR_E_SHIM_LEGACYRUNTIMEALREADYBOUND not what I stated before. Apparently windows Err.exe cant process 0x8013xxx codes properly

Comment: @JoshuaMJEze how did you solve it?